# Nuxt 3 hard redirect

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

The Nuxt3 app I'm building has the following pages:

1. home page
2. action page (auth protected)

In order to check if the user is authenticated and handles redirects, I created a `useAuth` composable.

```js
// composables/useAuth.js

export default async () => {
  const isAuth = await checkIfAuth();

  if (!isAuth) {
    return navigateTo("/");
  }
  
  return null;
};
```

Then on the page:

```js
// pages/action.vue

<script setup>
await useAuth();
</script>

<template>
...
</template>
```

The thing is that in `pages/index.vue` I'm fetching some data from the API, while I redirect that fetch doesn't happen on the server but on the client, which is not the way I want.

Is there any way in Nuxt3 to "hard redirect" or redirect but fetch the data on the server?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the `server` directory in the doc. Because otherwise no, you can't make a call from within the server afterwards (once you're using the SPA, you will not render anymore on the server).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What exactly on the `server`? Shall I do the redirects on the server middleware?

Comment: Not sure if a redirect is directly feasible form there but you can always make a middleware + router push on the client side yeah.

Comment: But then I have the same issue, it tries to fetch the data on client, I don't want that.

Comment: If you fetch the data on the `server` directory, it will be on the server routes AFAIK.